# App removed in playstore cause using Device Administration in android Malformed AndroidManifest (android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED)

Tags: device-admin

my app had been removed on play store cause

REASON FOR SUSPENSION: Violation of the dangerous products provision of the Content Policy:

We don't allow content that harms, interferes with the operation of, or accesses in an unauthorized manner, networks, servers, or other infrastructure.
After a regular review, we have determined that your app has a malformed AndroidManifest.xml file which may make it difficult for users to uninstall the app.

In particular, the app’s AndroidManifest.xml contains a malformed Device Admin receiver entry (as identified by meta-data named android.app.device_admin). To be a well-formed Device Admin, the entry must declare an Intent filter for Intents with action android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED. The suggested modification is to make the entry well-formed if the receiver is a Device Admin, or remove the meta-data named android.app.device_admin if the receiver is not a Device Admin.

This particular app has been disabled as a policy strike. If your developer account is still in good standing, you may revise and upload a policy compliant version of this application as a new package name.

I still dont understand why they removed it,
i using in manifest is same with other app in play store, 
could anyone help me know why may app had removed :S, so sad

So is it possible to create such a method without a violation of the terms?

```
<receiver
     android:name=".DeviceAdminDemoReceiver"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
     <intent-filter>

            <!-- This action is required -->
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- This is required this receiver to become device admin component. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/uses_policies" />
    </receiver>
```

Comment: does someone have same?

Comment: @JavaForAndroid can you help me?

Comment: The Manifest syntax looks, correct, it is the same as an app I have published. I would guess, like my app, the DeviceAdmin is used to make the uninstall or the force stopping of the app difficult. I suspect your app was flagged by a user who disagreed with that philosophy. In our case, our customers requested the feature, so are unlikely to complain that the app performs this function.